# Object return three open close quote in PHP LARAVEL

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I need to pass my object data to onclick javascript but my console return syntax error , I assume that the caused is my object data because the other object were fine . Below is the example of my data

[image]

First of all , why my object data return 3 open close quote ? because of that i assume that my javascript cant be passed . here my example of code

```xml
@if (!empty($paginationRecord))
    @foreach ($paginationRecord as $i => $known)
        @php 
            $semicolon = array(";");
            $break = array("<br>");
            $newphrase = str_replace($semicolon, $break, $known['ke_problem']); // ke_problem is my object return
            echo $newphrase ; 
        @endphp
        <a style="word-wrap: break-word" href="#" onclick="returnToCaller('{{  $newphrase }}');" title="Passing data back to the respective caller" class="crudlink"> ADD DESCRIPTION </a> 
    @endforeach
@endif
```

my javascript function

```
function returnToCaller(data) {
    console.log(data);
    window.opener.getChildValError(data);
    window.close();
    return false; 
}
```

Comment: _“First of all , why my object data return 3 open close quote ?”_ - no, _first_ of all, what _is_ that even that we are looking at here? Probably a screenshot from dev tools or something, but not the actual source code. I doubt the triple quotes are actually in the source code.

Comment: The problem is that you have line breaks in your content, which you can not have in a basic JS string literal. Either use ES6 template string syntax that allows them, or _remove_ them before you output the value as a JS string.

Comment: Your first comment there is a bit arsey @CBroe. No need for it. Let's play nicely?

Comment: the 3 quotes are something that the vardumper components wraps the string around to indicate that it's a multiline string. It's not actually in your variable. Check [the vardumper examples](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper.html#dump-examples-and-output) for more information

Comment: No images of code or error messages please, just plain good'old ASCII text.

Answer (score 0):

We have have option **json_encode** in laravel and its simple

```
@if (!empty($paginationRecord))
@foreach ($paginationRecord as $i => $known)
    <a style="word-wrap: break-word" href="#" onclick="returnToCaller('{{json_encode($newphrase)}}');" title="Passing data back to the respective caller" class="crudlink"> ADD DESCRIPTION </a> 
@endforeach
@endif
```

Javascript

```
function returnToCaller(data) {
console.log(JSON.parse(data));
```

}

Comment: try this its 100% works, suppose if you have speacial character in your object try this onclick="returnToCaller({{json_encode($newphrase,JSON_INVALID_UTF8_IGNORE)}});"